# Design of background client application

Tags: c#

I am having to design a client application that will be installed on all computers in our company that will collect and report hardware and software information for inventory purposes to a SQL database.  The application may need to be updated remotely and possibly some parameters such as polling time period be updated remotely as well.  I am not entirely sure of the best way to architect this type of application.  In trying to research and think this through I have come up with the following options:

- write a Windows Service that would always run automatically, anytime a computer booted up and on a Timer have it perform the necessary inventory functions.
- write a Windows Service that acts like base platform for future expansions, but contain the actual inventory client in a Forms/WPF app that is minimized to the system tray and can be opened to change settings.  The Windows Service would verify that the Forms/WPF app is always running and handle any management tasks such as possibly performing upgrades on the Forms/WPF app.
- write just a Forms/WPF app that is configured to run on Startup.  It would be minimized to the system tray and on a timer perform the inventory function and report to the database.

That is the three main options I have come up with.  I'm hoping someone who has tackled a problem like this in the past can provide some insight into how they designed their project.  Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: It could be the information you need can be acquired remotely. See Sysinternals PSinfo.

Comment: We have done that some in the past, but want something more reliable regardless of the computers location.  Example:  We cannot retrieve information remotely on computers connected over VPN.  However, those remote computers can reliably hit internal resources on our network.  That's why we want a client on each computer.

Comment: Just want to be sure you are not reinventing the wheel, since modern OS can do all the described things (provide system info, auto-update software, execute processes remotely, etc.)

Comment: Yeah.  We want a client that actively checks in with a database that can also be leveraged for other tasks like auditing hard disk encryption and any other tasks our CIO wants.  Just trying to figure out the most robust design.  Our previous method was a service that scans all the computers and runs WMI queries, but, as I mentioned in my previous comment, this cannot connect to computers over VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has a similar question, the path I've ended up taking is to create a Windows Service that has all of its main logic in a separate dll and has a separate program for updating.  The Update program stops the service, moves/overwrites the dll's for the service and then restarts the service.  The main dll that the Service runs processes on a polling/timer feature and periodically checks for and downloads updates and then can schedule the Update program to run.  I found a great example [here](https://anordinarydeveloper.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/writing-a-self-updating-windows-service/).

Even though I've already chosen how I am going to implement this project, I am still open to hearing how others have handled similar situations.